# TypeScript function returning undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a method in a the class below:

```
export class SearchService {
  userUID: string;
  searchItems: any;
  private searchesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection;

  constructor(
    private db: AngularFirestore,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  ) {
  }

  getSearches() {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      this.userUID = user['uid'];
      this.searchesCollection = this.db.collection(`users/${this.userUID}/searches`);
      this.searchItems = this.searchesCollection.valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data); // works
        return data;
      });
    });
    console.log(this.searchItems); // undefined
    return this.searchItems; //undefined
  }

}
```

My issue is with the return statement, it is returning undefined. The console.log(data) a few lines above it returns the value I want. I am wondering why I am getting undefined. It might be a scoping issue but I can't seem to figure it out. What am I overlooking?

Comment: The reason is that `this.afAuth.authState` is asynchronous.

Comment: The subscribe function is what it sounds like, you subscribe for the newspaper that will arrive on monday. It will trigger sometime in the future. When you return `this.searchItems`, the future has not happened yet.

Comment: It is how observable works.  searchItems is not defined because there is no guarantee that the observable returned a value yet.

Comment: @ippi should I be using another function like .map?

Comment: No, this is normal. You request something from the database, you don't know if it'll be back in a second or in an hour - you can only hope. The question is not how to get the value instantly. It may add some needed steps to your thinking (and debugging!) but that's just how it is.

Comment: @ippi got it, thanks for the knowledge

Comment: It's angular. you can almost certainly just bind the data to your template anyway and it'll show up when ready. Try doing a `<pre>{{searchItems | json}}</pre>` in your template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working with **[async programming](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript)**  you cannot pause the execution of the code and your subscription will be resolved in future but you cannot predict when.  `console.log()` outside the `subscribe` is executed before your subscription is resolved that's why it's undefined
  and `console.log()` inside subscribe call back is invoked  after the subscription is resolved.
Refer **[this](https://developer.telerik.com/topics/web-development/introduction-observables-angular-developers/)** for better understanding.
what you can do is You can store the value in a class property and access it in your template.

```
  getSearches() {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      this.userUID = user['uid'];
      this.searchesCollection = this.db.collection(`users/${this.userUID}/searches`);
   this.searchesCollection.valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data); // works
         this.searchItems=data;
      });
    });
    console.log(this.searchItems); // undefined
    return this.searchItems; //undefined
  }
```

**HTML**

```
  {{searchItems?.//property}}
```

or you can use `async pipe`
AsyncPipe accepts as an argument an `observable` or a promise, calls `subscribe` or attaches a then handler, then waits for the asynchronous result before passing it through to the caller.

```
 getSearches() {
        this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
          this.userUID = user['uid'];
          this.searchesCollection = this.db.collection(`users/${this.userUID}/searches`);
       this.searchItems=this.searchesCollection.valueChanges();

      }
```

**HTML**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of searchItems|async">
      {{item?.//property}}
<ng-container>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbe9jg)**

Comment: thanks for you answer! its very well explained. I will give it a shot and accept it as answer as soon as i figure it out!

Comment: although your answer isnt exactly what was needed to solve my issue, your answer and code lead me to the solution so i marked it as the answer. thanks! in case you are interested, i had to use snapshotChanges.map() instead of subscribe along with the async pipe you mentioned. i found snapshot() here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md

Comment: Glad I could help and Thanx for the link you provided.:)

Answer (score 1):

```
 getSearches() {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      this.userUID = user['uid'];
      this.searchesCollection = this.db.collection(`users/${this.userUID}/searches`);
      this.searchItems = this.searchesCollection.valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data); // works
        return data;
      });
    });
    console.log(this.searchItems); // undefined
    return this.searchItems; //
```

there is an async call in this. Since you are returning the value before your call is resolved or comes back you will not have data in `this.searchItems`
since you are using a call to server or to db, use observable to take advantage of Angular's promise concept.