# getting an Undefined variable in Angular http get subscribe response

Tags: angular

I have in a service 'work-orders.service.ts' a http get like :

```
getWorkOrderById(workOrderID: number): Observable<any> {
    const options = new RequestOptions({
      headers: new Headers({
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      })
    });
    return this.http.get(uri + `/api/workorder/${workOrderID}`, options)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
  }
```

and consuming the service in 'report-view.component.ts' I have :

```
export class ReportsViewComponent implements OnInit {
.
.
  wEndTime: string;
  wStartTime: string;
```

then I have the Constrauctor with the

```
constractor (private workOrderService: WorkOrdersService)

ngOnInit() {

   this.getWorkOrder(this.workOrderId); // I get 'workOrderId' as @Input


}
```

and the function :

```
getWorkOrder(id) {
    this.workOrderService.getWorkOrderById(id)
      .subscribe( (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.wStartTime = response.WorkOrderStartTime;
        this.wEndTime = response.WorkOrderEndTime;
      }) ;
  }
```

everything is working except I see that `this.wStartTime` and  `this.wEndTime` are always Undefined and not getting the values from the response .
The response is an Object .

> What is wrong , and how can I get data from the response to the
>   'Outside world' ?

Comment: after you print out `response`, see if you have `WorkOrderStartTime` inside the properties tree. If not, try find out why?

Comment: Check the service response in the Network tab of developers tool

Comment: where does it show undefined,  where are you accessing it?

Comment: thanks @windmaomao . in the response properties i see the WorkOrderStartTime with his VALUE .

Comment: Hi @Vikas , I see the undifined in the VC debuger .

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50616097/typescript-function-returning-undefined/50616318#50616318)

Comment: If both of your `wStartTime` and `wEndTime` are populated, you shouldn't get any errors. I'm missing something. Make sure both of these varaibles are set to empty string under class definition.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you do not need `.map(response => response.json())` in the 'work-orders.service.ts' file.

I understand that the fetch package uses response.json() (which returns a promise which will resolve to the response JSON object), but for angulars http package they already parse the response to a JSON object. So you should be able to access `this.wStartTime = response.WorkOrderStartTime;` and `this.wEndTime = response.WorkOrderEndTime;` directly from the response object that you get in the subscription's success callback.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a function to getWorkerOrder

```
getWorkOrder(id, fn) {
    this.workOrderService.getWorkOrderById(id)
    .subscribe( (response) => {
        fn(response.WorkOrderStartTime, response.WorkOrderEndTime);
     }) ;
}
```

Then:

```
var a, b;
var self = this;
// Could be more like typescript, sorry.
function someConsumer(a, b) {
   self.a = a; // this.a should be bound by Angular
   self.b = b; // b as well
}

ngOnInit() {
   this.getWorkOrder(this.workOrderId, someConsumer); 
}
```

Comment: Hi @atmin, I don't understand ! . what about  `wEndTime` and  `wStartTime` in my code ? how    can I put the values in them ?

Comment: @NoahB: its functional. Function someConsumer takes the variables. And you can do whatever you want with it in your scope, and you should be in scope. I will edit my answer. Though it won't be perfect, cause I don't remember Typescript at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

After a long try and consultation with others , i discovered the problem and i share the solution with you .
The problem lyes when i do **consecutive** API calls using Http Observables.
As in my code, i have two consecutive HTTP API calls (only the last one seen in the code I gave!).
So it happens that in the second HTTP request I can't get the results :

`this.wStartTime = response.WorkOrderStartTime;
this.wEndTime = response.WorkOrderEndTime;`

The solution in such cases is to use async/await features.
So doing :

```
async ngOnInit()
{
 firstCallToAPI();
 await secondCallToAPI(); // where I'm doing the this.wStartTime = response.WorkOrderStartTime; ect.
}
```

Hope it helps !!