# Console output shows "undefined" when attempting to retrieve and map JSON data in Angular 6

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm trying to learn how to get JSON data from an api, parse and map it to my type and then display it in an angular material datatable. However when I check my console output, it shows the value as undefined. I haven't even got as far as creating the datatable.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? I'm using Angular 6.1.0:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from '../../node_modules/rxjs';    

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


export class AppComponent {
  title = 'NgTable';
  myPlace = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";  
  myPosts: Observable<posts[]>;  
  myPostArr: posts[];

  constructor(http: HttpClient){
    this.myPosts = http.get<posts[]>(this.myPlace);
    this.myPosts.subscribe(response => {this.myPostArr = response});

    console.log(this.myPostArr);
  }
}

export interface posts {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}
```

output of console.log is: *undefined*

Comment: Your console log could simply be happening before the subscription has fired. Try putting the console log just under the `this.myPostArr = response` (inside the scope of the subscription). This being said, it is better to put all your HTTP requests within a service, rather than just within the component, and also call said service (or HTTP if you insist) inside of the ngOnInit method, rather than the constructor of the component.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [typescript function returning undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50616097/typescript-function-returning-undefined)

Comment: Thanks @JamesMacca - I definitely agree with your suggestion in putting it in a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to async nature of observable, this.myPostArr gets data at some point of time
  So, out side of subscribe block, it won't be resolved when that line executes.

I will suggest you to put all your http methods in a service and return `Observables`.

```
constructor(http: HttpClient){
    this.myPosts = http.get<posts[]>(this.myPlace);
    this.myPosts.subscribe(response => {this.myPostArr = response;

    console.log(this.myPostArr);
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation - I did as you suggested and it works